# UITableViewController setting delegates and datasource

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uitableview

I'm a little bit confused about UITableViewController... As far as I concern they are typically the delegate and datasource of the UITableView (although it can be made such that they are different).

However in some cases, like when embedding a UITableViewController in a UITabBarViewController in Interface Builder, we initiate our table view controller in IB. Therefore in my understanding, the default initialiser is being called.

But in this case, I have this piece of code:

```
@interface Settings : UITableViewController {

}
```

And in the IB I see that the delegate and datasource of the UITableView is hooked up to this class. My question is, why is it that we don't need to explicitly say that it is following:

```
@interface Settings : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>     
{
}
```

And in the .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [tableView setDelegate:self];
    [tableView setDataSource:self];
}
```

I have indeed stumbled upon some cases where I have to explicitly code the above a few times to make something work. Although it is still a mystery for me as of why it is needed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the angle brackets behind the superclass, you can define which Protocols your class is going to implement. Protocols contain (like interfaces in Java) method declarations, but no implementation. Some of the methods are marked as required, some as optional. I.e. if you decide to implement a protocol, you at least have to implement the required ones.

However, you do not need to indicate that you are going to implement a protocol. It is enough to implement the required ones and your delegate will work fine. It is a good idea to indicate it, though. Xcode and the compiler are going to warn you if either of both detect errors in your implementation (like forgetting a required method, using a wrong method signature etc.).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. What about setting delegate and datasource to self? Is that actually needed?

Comment: Yes, this is needed, since by this you define on which object the delegate methods are invoked. You can imagine this as the tableView "asking" the delegate and the dataSource how many rows, sections etc. it is supposed to display and how the cells look like. So you must tell the tableView which object is the delegate (i.e. who to ask).

Comment: Thanks Björn, but when creating a new file which is a UITableViewController subclass, both the delegate and datasource will be hooked up to the file itself in IB. This means that in this case I won't have to do this manually right?

Comment: Right, you can do it in Interface Builder or programmatically.

Comment: When you create a UITableViewController it is the delegate as well as the data source of its corresponding table view by default.

Comment: My problem was I have the UITableViewController and then I defined then I created a new class called "MasterTableViewController" but I had forgotten to set my UITableViewController in the StoryBoard to inherit from this class. So I went to UITableViewController and clicked on the "Show Identity Inspector" button in Interface Builder and selected my class. Then I could drag the delegate and datasource onto my UITableViewController.

Answer (score -5):

use

tableView.delegate=self;
 tableView.dataSource=self;

instead of

```
[tableView setDelegate:self];
[tableView setDataSource:self];
```

Comment: No. Those implementations are equivalent.